# Pandas concat : Incorrect total length after dataframes are concatenated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate 2 dataframes.

'data' df looks like below (length = 6260):

```
tail

                           bs     forecast
2016-09-25 17:15:00  2.371138     NaN
2016-09-25 17:20:00  2.611324     NaN
2016-09-25 17:25:00  2.503655     NaN
2016-09-25 17:30:00  2.439995     NaN
2016-09-25 17:35:00  3.140531     NaN
```

'future' df looks like below (length = 289):

```
head

                      bs     forecast
2016-09-25 23:55:00  NaN      NaN
2016-09-26 00:00:00  NaN      NaN
2016-09-26 00:05:00  NaN      NaN
2016-09-26 00:10:00  NaN      NaN
2016-09-26 00:15:00  NaN      NaN

tail

                      bs     forecast 
2016-09-26 23:35:00  NaN     NaN 
2016-09-26 23:40:00  NaN     NaN
2016-09-26 23:45:00  NaN     NaN
2016-09-26 23:50:00  NaN     NaN
2016-09-26 23:55:00  NaN     NaN
```

Then, I concatenated  both dfs like so:

```
data = pd.concat([data, future])
```

The results came out as I wanted:

```
                           bs     forecast
2016-09-25 17:35:00  3.140531     NaN
2016-09-25 23:55:00  NaN          NaN
2016-09-26 00:00:00  NaN          NaN
2016-09-26 00:05:00  NaN          NaN
2016-09-26 00:10:00  NaN          NaN
2016-09-26 00:15:00  NaN          NaN
```

However, when I checked the length of "data", it is 6518 instead of 6549 (6260+289).

Is it suppose to work like this? or did I do something wrong?

What happened to the rest of the 31 rows ? (6549 - 6518)

Comment: No!  It's not.  There must be something with your data that's causing it.  I'm not creative enough to imagine up a scenario in which that could happen.  Your best bet is to provide an example of where it does happen and share that with us.  try to adhere to the standards laid out in this post http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You're right, I found out that I assigned "data" to itself after getting rid of outliers, which I missed. Thus, the shortened length.